# Cannot use maths in order by with subquery - column doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, subquery, sql-order-by

I have two tables with data:

```
create table table_one (table_two_id integer, ranking numeric);
create table table_two (id integer);

insert into table_one (table_two_id, ranking) values (1, 5);
insert into table_one (table_two_id, ranking) values (2, 10);

insert into table_two (id) values (1);
insert into table_two (id) values (2);
```

I can query and order like this:

```
select 
  (select ranking from table_one where table_two_id = tbl_2.id) as ranking,
  id
from table_two as tbl_2 order by ranking desc;
```

But if I want to alter the `order by` query to use a bit of maths:

```
select 
  (select ranking from table_one where table_two_id = tbl_2.id) as ranking,
  id
from table_two as tbl_2 order by ranking * 1 desc;
```

I get `ERROR: column "ranking" does not exist Position: 123`.

Note that I can order by ranking just fine when not using the subselect:

```
select ranking from table_one order by ranking / 1;
```

Reproduction here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b88bc/12, Postgres 9.6.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your 'ranking' is a mistake :

```
select 
  tbl_1.ranking,
  id
from table_two as tbl_2 
  inner join table_one as tbl_1
  on tbl_1.table_two_id = tbl_2.id
order by tbl_1.ranking * 1 desc;
```

You can make sure of that by running this query :

```
select 
  (select ranking from table_one where table_two_id = tbl_2.id),
  id
from table_two as tbl_2 
order by ranking desc;
```

As you can see the ranking used is in fact directly the one from table_one. The engine has redesigned the query to make it worked.

Picture this as the aliasing has to be made after the all calculation of your query. In this situation it is quite clear that your order by cannot find a column that is not already named.

You can verify has follows :

```
with cte as 
(
select 
  (select ranking from table_one where table_two_id = tbl_2.id) as ranking,
  id
from table_two as tbl_2 
)
select *
from cte
order by ranking *1 desc;
```

And a little advice : avoid if it is possible to run subqueries in the select part of your query. It is a lot work to process for your engine if it does not find a way to rewrite properly the query. Picture it as it take a new query for each resultat line of the first result of your query. Of course there is exceptions but think it through before doing it and justify to yourself why using it in place of a proper join.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed reply.  I understand that Postgres will try to reform a subselect into a join to be more efficient, but I don't understand why this would cause `order by ranking * 1` to fail, as a join can be ordered both by `ranking` and `ranking * 1`.  What am I missing?

Comment: In fact there is an explanation but it seems old : (quote)ORDER BY (and also GROUP BY) permit references to output column names
only when they are *unadorned*.  You cannot use them in expressions. This is a compromise between SQL92 and SQL99 rules ... it's a bit ugly (end of quote).https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1632.1128539471@sss.pgh.pa.us